# Will a universal docking station help speed up my desktop graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, docking-station

I have a Dell XPS 15 9530 (late 2013 edition).

It's pretty quick, but I have hooked up an external 4k monitor via DisplayPort and desktop graphics have very much slowed down.

Would something like [Dell's D3100](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&sku=452-bbpg) relieve my laptop of some of the stress of powering a second high resolution monitor?

Or is the only benefit of such things more ports?

Comment: No; It would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not help in this case. You can check [its specs on Dell's site](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&sku=452-bbpg) and nowhere does it mention that is comes with its of GPU or any other way to accellerating graphics.

What you want is real external GPU, and hook the 4K screen onto that.
Basically, for more high res. screens you want more graphics power. The XPS 15 9530 seems to lack options for that though. USB3 to a real card is possibly, but pccard, MXM or thunderbolt would be a lot better.